# PHP Amazon SDK - s3 putObject and set Body

Tags: php, object, sdk, amazon-s3, put

hi i'm trying putting a new object into a bucket with this code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

require_once(FCPATH.'s3/aws-autoloader.php');

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class s3{
    public $_secret_key ="********";
    public $_access_key = "********"; 
    public $_bucket = "tphotos-dev";

 function connect(){

     return  S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => $this->_access_key,
    'secret' => $this->_secret_key,
));


 }
 function deleteObject($prefix = false){
    if($prefix){
        $s3 = $this->connect();
        return $s3->deleteMatchingObjects($this->_bucket, $prefix);
    }
 }

 function putObject($file_name,$source_file){
    $s3 = $this->connect();
     $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => (string)$this->_bucket,
    'Key'    => $file_name,
    'SourceFile'   => $source_file,
    'ACL'         => 'public-read',
    ));
    return $s3->waitUntilObjectExists(array(
    'Bucket' => $this->_bucket,
    'Key'    => $file_name
    ));

 }  

}
```

?>

so once i do for example:

```
$s3->putObject('myfilename.jpg',get_file_content("temp/image.jpg"));
```

it returns error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'You must specify a non-null value for the Body or SourceFile parameters.' in /Users/ok/Projects/s3/Aws/Common/Client/UploadBodyListener.php:91
```

any clue ?

Comment: In my case it was because I had a limit on 
**upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** because $source_file doesn't come (is null),  the server validate $source_file > upload_max_filesize or post_max_size.

Comment: In my case the error seemed to indicate that the SourceFile (source file path) was null, but actually it wasn't null, it was just invalid. For those that end up here, check the source file path. Or as in the case of the OP, if you're passing the entire contents of the file instead of just the file path, use the parameter 'Body' instead of 'SourceFile'.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sorry i got the fix:

it was just to change this

```
'SourceFile'   => $source_file,
```

to

```
'Body'   => $source_file,
```

Comment: Hi Could you please help me. When try to use the same function I am getting 403 response.

Comment: Thanks @sbaaaang, but why? 
documentation says http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#uploading-a-file 
Version sdk 2

Comment: Thanks @sbaaaang.
SourceFile is work in direct path.but not working in temp folder to upload file.why this happen.??

Comment: I was having a similar issue. I just discovered it might have been because of a few of my URLs ended with a query string.  Beware the query string when uploading file to S3.

Comment: Actually this doesnt work with images. When i try to open them in AWS S3, I don't the mime-type for the jpgs when uploaded as  'Body' works. I think it thinks they are plain text. I reverted back to SourceFile and now since i don't have query string in my paths its working great.

Comment: @RobinGomez - The link you provided is for "Uploading a file" where you pass the file path, but he's actually passing the contents of the file, not the path. See the section "Uploading from a stream" further down the same page for the version that he needs using the 'Body' parameter.